# Setting a sessionScoped bean from stateless service?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a webservice. This WS gets injected a sessionscoped bean. I want to use that bean some time after the webservice method was executed. But the bean is always empty:

```
@Stateless class Webservice () {
    @Inject SessionBean sessionBean;

    public exposedMethod() {
        sessionBean.setParam("test");
    }
}

@WebServlet class Servlet() {
    @Inject SessionBean sessionBean;

    public doGet(..) {
        String test = sessionBean.getParam();
        System.out.println(test); //null;
    }
}

@SessionScoped SessionBean() implements Serializable {
    private param;
    void getParam() { return param; }
    void setParam(String param) { this.param = param; }
}
```

Execution:
1. call WS
2. go to /myapp/servletname

Result: "null"
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct the annotation. It must be

```
@Inject SessionBean sessionBean;
```